# How to disable add with condition in array input react admin

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-admin, api-platform.com

I have an object with a Json array as a field:

```
{
   name: "test",
   field: [
           {name: "field1",value: "value1"},
           {name: "field2",value: "value2"}
  ]
}
```

I am using api platform as a data provider.
I am using EditGuesser of react admin as follows:

```
const SetsEdit = (props:any) => (
<EditGuesser {...props}>
        <InputGuesser source="name" />
        <ArrayInput source="field">
            <SimpleFormIterator inline disableAdd={disableAdd(props)}>
                <TextInput source="name" helperText={false} />
                <TextInput source="value" helperText={false} />
            </SimpleFormIterator>
        </ArrayInput>
</EditGuesser>
);
```

And I'm using the edit guesser in hydra admin

```
<HydraAdmin
            dataProvider={dataProvider(setRedirectToLogin)}
            layout={MyLayout}
            loginPage={LoginPage}>
            <ResourceGuesser
                name="sets"
                edit={SetsEdit}
            />

        </HydraAdmin>
```

What I am trying to do is I want to disable Add when field.length is >= to 4.
So I want to add a condition to the prop disableAdd based on the value of the object.
How do I pass the object value to the function to return true or false.

Comment: post where you pass the props

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka The prop is disableAdd, it's a boolean, I need to give it true if field.length>=4 and false if not. I don't know how to access the value of field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to watch for the actual form data using [react-hook-form's `useWatch`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usewatch)  or [react-admin's `<FormDataConsumer>`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#hiding-inputs-based-on-other-inputs), and use that data in your `disableAdd` prop.

Something like (not tested):

```
const SetsEdit = (props:any) => (
    <EditGuesser {...props}>
        <InputGuesser source="name" />
        <FormDataConsumer>
             {({ formData }) => (
                <ArrayInput source="field">
                    <SimpleFormIterator inline disableAdd={disableAdd(formData)}>
                        <TextInput source="name" helperText={false} />
                        <TextInput source="value" helperText={false} />
                    </SimpleFormIterator>
                </ArrayInput>
             )}
        </FormDataConsumer>
    </EditGuesser>
);
```